# React ajax render

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm having troubles to render my components with ajax data.

I do not know how to insert a component inside my render with the ajax data.

Here is my AccountPage.js

```
import Close from '../../icons/Close'
import Delete from '../../icons/Delete'
import Edit from '../../icons/Edit'
import List from '../../icons/List'
import AccountSimple from './AccountSimple'
import '../../../../css/accounts.css'

class AccountPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null,
            first_name: '',
            account: '',
            address: '',
            tableBody: undefined

        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body");
        this.serverRequest = $.get("/api/client.json", function (result) {
          var client = result;
          this.setState({
             data: client,
          });
        }.bind(this));

    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // logs all objects from ajax
        console.log(data); 
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="contactto-middle-content">
            <h1 className="account-title">Usuários</h1>
            <div className="account-table">
              <div className="account-table-row account-table-row-header">
                  <div className="account-table-row-header-td account-table-td-name">Nome</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-header-td account-table-td-account">Conta</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-header-td account-table-td-address">Endereço</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-header-td account-table-td-actions">Ações</div>
              </div>
              <div id="table-body" className="account-table-row account-table-row-body">

              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default AccountPage
```

The AccountPage imports the AccountSimple

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import Done from '../../icons/Done'
import Close from '../../icons/Close'
import Delete from '../../icons/Delete'
import Edit from '../../icons/Edit'
import List from '../../icons/List'
import '../../../../css/accounts.css'

class AccountSimple extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          first_name: '',
          account: '',
          address: ''

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
          this.setState({
            first_name: this.props.acc.first_name,
            last_name: this.props.acc.last_name,
            account: this.props.acc.account,
            address: this.props.acc.address
          });
          console.log(this.props.acc);

    }

    render() {

        return (
                <div className="account-table-row-body-tr">
                  <div className="account-table-row-body-td account-table-td-name">{this.state.first_name} {this.state.last_name}</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-body-td account-table-td-account">{this.state.account}</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-body-td account-table-td-address">{this.state.address}</div>
                  <div className="account-table-row-body-td account-table-td-actions">
                    <List svgClass="account-table-td-actions-list" width="24" height="24" />
                    <Edit svgClass="account-table-td-actions-edit" width="24" height="24" />
                    <Delete svgClass="account-table-td-actions-delete" width="24" height="24" />
                  </div>
                </div>

        );
    }
}

export default AccountSimple
```

What I want is render #  inside the render of AccountPage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to render what inside the render of AccountPage? What's "#"?

Comment: for exaple: I have 3 account objects at my json, I want to render 3 <AccountSimple /> components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to `.map` over the objects in `data` (assuming it's an array) and create an `AccountSimple` component for each. **You don't need state** in `AccountSimple` - just use props.

Inside `AccountPage#render`:

```
<div id="table-body" className="account-table-row account-table-row-body">
    { data && data.map(accountInfo =>
        <AccountSimple {...accountInfo} />
    )}
</div>
```

This checks whether `data` has been loaded, and then when it's available, passes each data row as props to `AccountSimple`.

`AccountSimple` should probably be a *stateless component* - it doesn't need a `constructor` or `componentDidMount` method, it can just have a `render` method and refer to `this.props` instead of `this.state`.

Comment: Ok, I am trying here and I back to tell if got